# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have searched around and I think my code is correct, but for some reason its still failing.

My controller:

```
$scope.unsubscribe = function()
  {
    bluetoothFactory.unsubscribe().then(function()
    {
      $scope.info = 'unsubscribe success';
    }, 
    function(error) 
    { 
      $scope.error = error;
    });
  };
```

My factory:

```
unsubscribe: function() {
      var q = $q.defer();
      $window.bluetoothSerial.unsubscribe().then(function (){
        q.resolve();
      }, function(error) {
        q.reject(error);
      });
      return q.promise();
    }
```

From my controller I just call: $scope.unsubscribe() and receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at Object.unsubscribe (bluetoothFactory.js:37)
    at Scope.$scope.unsubscribe (bluetoothController.js:84)
    at Scope.$scope.submitReads (bluetoothController.js:118)
    at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
    at ionic.bundle.js:53458
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
    at HTMLButtonElement.m.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Kinda surprised you don't get an error here: `return q.promise();` `promise` should be returned, not executed.

Comment: It appears that `$window.bluetoothSerial.unsubscribe()` isn't returning a promise. Can you add that section of code to the question?

Comment: Also @KevinB is correct - you should be returning `q.$promise` not `q.promise()`.

Comment: Oh, **because you aren't getting to that line yet**. :) that would have been the next problem. Problem is with `bluetoothSerial`'s `unsubscribe` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only wrap promises if I need to do some processing on the data before it reaches the controller. You aren't doing that here. If `$window.bluetoothSerial` already returns a promise you aren't adding any value by wrapping it in another promise.

The other thing is that Angular `$q` `deferred`s are a little different than jQuery `deferred`s. To return a promise use `return q.promise` instead of `return q.promise()`.

Your factory doesn't really do anything so you could do it a couple ways:

```
unsubscribe: $window.bluetoothSerial.unsubscribe
```

or

```
unsubscribe: function() { return $window.bluetoothSerial.unsubsribe(); }
```

Comment: how would change my code to not return a second promise?

Comment: I removed the () and its still not working. I assume its the double promise. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I removed the promise completely and it worked perfect.